# MS SQL Server Agent job delivers only a partial result compared to when run manually

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, jobs, sql-server-agent

I have a question regarding the SQL SEVER Agent. Every night I execute a series of stored procedures. This worked fine for a while. But since a couple of days I noticed that the results of the agent differ from the results of when I execute the procedure manually.

Trouble is that there is no error message. It's not even an empty result, it's a PARTIAL result.

The procedure where it seems to 'fail' is a recursive one that generates a hierarchy.

So far I found out that it might have something to do with the user rights. SA is the owner of the job, yet the job is executed via a separate special Server Agent User, as it seems, which is called NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT. So I gave this user all the rights it might logically need, ran the job manually (via the agent) and actually got the right results! All seemed fine, until I discovered this morning that the job went wrong again over the weekend.

I’ve run out of ideas at this point. Do you have any?

This the statement I copied into the step:

```
USE [CAE]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[Indirect_Asso_Procedure]

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

As you can see it's completely standard.

Comment: To try to understand if it's an user right problem I'd use a proxy account to run the job. More info about proxies: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/us-en/library/ms189064(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: The problem sometimes is the timeframe of the execution of the job. Another job might be running at the same time locking tables or deleting rows.

Comment: What are the results, and how do you know they're partial? What's missing compared to the "full" result? Is there any rhyme or reason to it that would allow you to conclude what the problem is? How long does the procedure take to execute when it runs in a satisfactory matter? You need to narrow down the differences between successful and unsuccessful runs to get at the actual problem, otherwise any answer will be nothing more than speculation.